# Get element where Event is binded

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am binding an event to an element either using `@click` property in Vue (it behaves the same as javascript `.onclick` property).

The problem I have is when the event is called by propagating from the child DOM nodes click events I get the child DOM element as `target` property and I cannot find a way a clean way (without searching for the parents, as the element might me nested deep inside) to access the DOM element that the event was registered onto inside the event callback.

```html
<td @click="onCellClick($event)">
  <div class="text">
    <span>default</span>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Try using `this`

Comment: I get the Vue instance since its inside a vuejs component when I use `this`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the confusion is with the event's `target` vs `currentTarget`

> event.target is what triggers the event dispatcher to trigger and event.currentTarget is what you assigned your listener to.

```
Vue.component('cell', {
  template: '#cell',
  methods: {
    onCellClick: function (e) {
      console.log(e.currentTarget)
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: That was it, the thing that confused me was that when I logged the event `currentTarget` was null. But its available in the callback so it works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref):

```
<td @click="onCellClick($event)" ref="cell1">
  <div class="text">
    <span>default</span>
  </div>
</td>

onCellClick(evt){
   console.log(this.$refs.cell1)
}
```

Comment: I have also thought of this but this becomes a problem when using `v-for` for list or grid.

Comment: you can overcome it by using the index for the ref name and sending the index to the function and then you can call it like: this.`$refs[index]`