# vue.js - v-on:change - can I pass value of the select's ID and the selected default value. And the sibling value as well?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have two select boxes:

```
<b-form-select :id="('os-field-'+items.name)"  required>
    <option v-for="names in items.versions" >
        {{ names.version }} {{ names.kernelVersion }} ({{ names.name }})
    </option>
</b-form-select>

<b-form-select :id="('status-field-'+items.name)" v-on:change="setOperatingSystem(this.$id,$event)" required>
    <option v-for="items in testStatus" >
        {{ items }}
    </option>
</b-form-select>
```

When I call my method `v-on:change="setOperatingSystem(this.$id,$event)"`, I want to pass in the ID of the dropdown *and* the value of what the user has selected. Ideally, I also grab the value of the sibling's selected value as well, but I can do that in my method.. The data comes from a back-end server and I'm populating this from a very large array of objects. Lots of data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get both the ID of the element triggering the event and query for any sibling elements using `$event.currentTarget` which would be the form element - you don't need to pass it separately as the info you need is already contained in `$event`

```
const formEl = $event.currentTarget;
const formId = formEl.id;
const siblings = Array.from(formEl.childNodes).map(n => n.value); // You'll get all siblings including the selected value - you may need to filter that as needed
```

EDIT (from the comments):

Actually, I have an idea what the problem may be. You are using the Bootstrap Vue form component and that [only has `submit` listed as an event](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-input/#native-and-custom-events) in it's docs. Can you try using the native modifier like this : `v-on:change.native` and see if it works? More details on this here : https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-input/#native-and-custom-events

Comment: when I call v-on:change="setOperatingSystem($event)", and looking at my method:

            setOperatingSystem($event){
                console.log('os',$event.currentTarget);
            },

I get the following in my console:

os undefined

Comment: Because of how Vue's event wrapper works, you may not see that value when you console log it. It will, however be available in that callback [see this question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45936485/get-element-where-event-is-binded)

Comment: When I console out those const's from above, I get the following:

Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

In theory this should work, but have no idea why it's not.

Comment: Can you share a JS Fiddle reproduction or the surrounding code for better context?

Comment: Actually, I have an idea what the problem may be. You are using the Bootstrap Vue form component and that only has [`submit` listed as an event](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-input/#native-and-custom-events) in it's docs. Can you try using the `native` modifier like this : `v-on:change.native` and see if it works? More details on this here : https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-input/#native-and-custom-events

Comment: Chirag - That's it exactly! Thank you very much!